# What is the most common reason I lose 4G?

Tags: communication

I only transiently have 4G on my phone. What is the main cause of its unavailablity?

I would have thought it was caused (in reality) by a weak signal from the base station that cannot carry the phones data above a critical error rate. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sometimes having no 4G means that the signal is too weak.
It works both ways, also the signal from your phone to the base station has to be strong enough to make the connection.
It might be possible to force your phone to stick to 4G but then the resulting data rate might be so low that 3G is a better option.